# XmlPullParser synchronization : threads are busy waiting

Tags: java, android, multithreading, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

I have a function for creating new XmlPullParser. My profiler is showing that threads are stuck at this point and this is a potential deadlock situation.

```
private static XmlPullParserFactory xmlPullParserFactory;

public static synchronized XmlPullParser newPullParser(InputStreamReader ip) throws Exception {
    if (xmlPullParserFactory == null) {
        xmlPullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    }

    final XmlPullParser parser = xmlPullParserFactory.newPullParser();
    parser.setInput(ip);
    return parser;
}
```

}

I am not able to figure out what is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not wrong but since the method is synchronized it seems to become the bottleneck.

Assuming that `XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance()` is threadsafe (is it?), you could simply drop the lazy creation of the factory (which is unnecessary since the factory is in heavy use) and then also drop the synchronized statement:

```
private static XmlPullParserFactory xmlPullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();

public static XmlPullParser newPullParser(InputStreamReader ip) throws Exception {
    final XmlPullParser parser = xmlPullParserFactory.newPullParser();
    parser.setInput(ip);
    return parser;
}
```